# I am getting error "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

Tags: sql-server

I am sending the string that I make in fom c# and I am sending it to a proceedure There I use it as nvarchar(1000) and then using it in the SQL IN operator but I am getting error "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

I am sending this

```
SET @a='E1554084-7B8F-4F04-B6B3-4892E4C5687F','4B555046-152B-411D-A611-D9D507906259'
```

in string builder and I want to use the comma as operator not as a string in sqlserver

```
SELECT * FROM MemberJobDetails WHERE GradeID IN (@a)
```

here GradeID is unique identifier

Comment: cast your string as a uniqueidentifier in your sql statement or try to simply put brackets around guid strings {...}

Comment: Your parameter `@a` is a **single string**, while the `IN` operator expects a **list of items** as its parameters....

Comment: A Single string that happens to *contain* commas is, logically, a different thing from multiple strings *separated* by commas. What you have is the former. Do a search for parameterizing `IN` on here and you'll find plenty of dupes with various (better or worse) solutions.

Comment: I have made some editing please kindly consider it

Answer (score 0):

```
Following query may help you

DECLARE @UID NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @UID='2A66057D-F4E5-4E2B-B2F1-38C51A96D385'
DECLARE @nUID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @nUID = CAST(@UID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
PRINT @nUID
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches

1 Dynamic SQL

```
declare @a varchar(1000)
SET @a='E1554084-7B8F-4F04-B6B3-4892E4C5687F,4B555046-152B-411D-A611-D9D507906259' 

set @a=''''+replace(@a,',',''',''')+''''

declare @sql varchar(8000)
set @sql='SELECT * FROM MemberJobDetails WHERE GradeID IN ('+@a+')'
exec(@sql)
```

2 Static SQL

```
SELECT * FROM MemberJobDetails WHERE ','+@a+',' like '%,'+GradeID+',%'
```